# ‘String or binary data would be truncated’

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am using entity framework to insert details into the database where I have a column varchar(50).
when I am trying to insert some value more than 50 length it gives me an error string or binary data would be truncated.So ., for safe side I just changed it to varchar(100).

Now can someone let me know is this the only solution to change the value in the Db or do we have any alternatives.......
I read an article http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/danny/archive/2008/01/12/scuffling-with-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated.aspx

But how can I use such things in c#. I appreciate any suggestions from you.........

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you showed the insert query/sproc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what type of input field you're dealing with, using [varchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) could be an option.

But as previously pointed out, it really boils down to what your business requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, obviously you cannot insert a string longer than 50 in a varchar(50).

So you have two options depending on your requirement:

- change the database (as you have found out) and make sure that all code 'upstream' will be able to tackle the longer data
- add some validations or restrict user input so that you will never get a string that is longer

Well, there's a third and that is cut off the string without telling the user but I would not do that.

So it depends on your business requirement what to do. But I would not do any 'tricks' like in the article you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You should set the field length in the db to whatever is a reasonable length and you should prevent users from entering values that does not fit within that length.

Answer (score 0):

1-when database table Alter when issue generated
2-First Backup table schema and data then delete table when re create table then run code .. working fine.